# React Native and Flutter Installation Invalid JAVA_HOME directory on Windows 10

Tags: android, react-native, flutter

I want to develop a mobile application for Android platform with React Native on Windows 10.
For the development environment I did the following steps:

1. I installed Android Studio.
2. Android SDK Platform 29
   I have installed `Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image or Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image` packages.
3. I added `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable.
4. I added the `platform-tools` environment variable.

I completed these steps, but when I tried to open the react native project in the simulator, I got the error invalid `JAVA_HOME`.
The full name of the error is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe` invalid `JAVA_HOME` error.

[image: Wrong JDK Environment Variable Value]

When I chose the correct file path of this exe it still didn't work. How can I solve this problem?

This problem can occur for flutter developers too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the development environment setup document of React Native, the solution for this error that occurs in Windows is not presented.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup

*Solution suggestion 1*: I solved this error as follows. Instead of `JDK`, it is necessary to add the `JRE` file path to `JAVA_HOME` environment variables.

[image: Correct environment variable value]

*Solution suggestion 2*: System Image files specified in the document did not work for my processor. If solution suggestion 1 did not resolve your error, try to find the System Image file suitable for your processor.

Good luck.